# (Almost) all apps hang on Mac while building an xCode project

Tags: xcode, performance

I'm encountering an issue on my mid-2012 Macbook Pro (system specs below). While performing an Xcode build of an Ionic project from the command line, I see (once every ten times or so?) the process stall and almost all apps hang or beachball.

I am generally able to switch between apps and open menus, but apps will not respond to clicks inside the window or on menu items. Tooltips still appear when I hover over items in the Dock and I am able to switch apps by clicking Dock items. When I try to shut down, it tells me that every single one of my apps is not responding, but even if I am able to force-quit them, I am not able to actually restart and instead have to hold down the power button.

Strangely, Terminal keeps responding through all of this, and I can open files and run new processes, however if I want to run a process that requires net access, such as `lynx`, the request times out.

I don't know where to start debugging this issue. Any insight on Mac-specific command line tools that would help analyze this while it's actually happening?

[image]

Output from `top`:

```
Processes: 338 total, 2 running, 24 stuck, 312 sleeping, 1627 threads                                                              12:46:40
Load Avg: 1.79, 2.46, 2.29  CPU usage: 0.24% user, 0.60% sys, 99.15% idle  SharedLibs: 152M resident, 44M data, 30M linkedit.
MemRegions: 54274 total, 4351M resident, 171M private, 1476M shared. PhysMem: 13G used (1986M wired), 2712M unused.
VM: 921G vsize, 633M framework vsize, 0(0) swapins, 0(0) swapouts. Networks: packets: 462429/214M in, 443918/192M out.
Disks: 1585475/28G read, 127563/2606M written.

PID   COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP PPID STATE    BOOSTS          %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS
3027  screencaptur 0.0  00:00.01 2     1    50    1428K  0B     0B     408  408  sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  1199
3026  top          2.7  00:02.07 1/1   0    21    4756K  0B     0B     3026 2884 running  *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    0    18310+
3025  syncdefaults 0.0  00:00.02 2     1    58    1836K  0B     0B     3025 1    sleeping *1[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  1485
3024  mdworker     0.0  00:00.03 3     2    53    3164K  0B     0B     3024 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2158
3023  mdworker     0.0  00:00.03 3     2    50    3096K  0B     0B     3023 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    89   2108
3021  AddressBookS 0.0  00:00.03 2     1    52    2144K  0B     0B     3021 1    sleeping *1[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2257
2884  bash         0.0  00:00.10 1     0    16    2632K  0B     0B     2884 2883 sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  4527
2883  login        0.0  00:00.01 2     1    29    1080K  0B     0B     2883 722  sleeping *0[9]           0.00000 0.00000    0    1038
2882  quicklookd   0.0  00:00.05 5     2    80    3372K  32K    0B     2882 1    sleeping  0[0]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2757
2881  ios-deploy   0.0  00:00.00 1     0    10    636K   0B     0B     2317 2318 stuck    *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  645
2848  mdworker     0.0  00:00.05 3     1    54    3156K  0B     0B     2848 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2184
2841  mdworker     0.0  00:00.13 3     1    62    3824K  0B     0B     2841 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  3326
2580  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.18 4     2    33    28M    0B     0B     2540 2540 sleeping *0[4]           0.00000 0.00000    501  11784
2578  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.19 4     2    33    29M    0B     0B     2541 2541 sleeping *0[6]           0.00000 0.00000    501  12087
2577  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.17 4     2    31    27M    0B     0B     2540 2540 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  10942
2576  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.24 4     2    34    28M    0B     0B     2538 2538 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  11651
2574  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.24 4     2    34    28M    0B     0B     2537 2537 sleeping *0[4]           0.00000 0.00000    501  11815
2573  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.23 4     2    33    28M    0B     0B     2539 2539 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  11588
2569  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.19 4     2    30    27M    0B     0B     2541 2541 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  10976
2558  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.19 4     2    30    27M    0B     0B     2537 2537 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  10977
2557  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.20 4     2    30    27M    0B     0B     2538 2538 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  10963
2556  Interface Bu 0.0  00:00.20 4     2    30    27M    0B     0B     2539 2539 sleeping *0[3]           0.00000 0.00000    501  10975
2542  ibtoold      0.0  00:01.15 7     3    98    45M-   0B     0B     2542 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  24004+
2541  ibtoold      0.0  00:01.51 7     3    105-  47M-   0B     0B     2541 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  27958+
2540  ibtoold      0.0  00:01.21 7     3    105   44M-   0B     0B     2540 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  24758+
2539  ibtoold      0.0  00:01.19 7     3    105   44M-   0B     0B     2539 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  24188+
2538  ibtoold      0.0  00:01.20 7     3    105   44M-   0B     0B     2538 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  24283+
2537  ibtoold      0.0  00:01.20 8     4    102+  44M-   0B     0B     2537 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  24321+
2471  mdworker     0.0  00:00.04 3     1    52    3132K  0B     0B     2471 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2570
2470  mdworker     0.0  00:00.04 3     1    52    3152K  0B     0B     2470 1    sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2576
2417- dbfseventsd  0.0  00:00.90 1     0    8     208K   0B     0B     422  2400 sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  202
2400- dbfseventsd  0.0  00:01.22 1     0    8     4344K  0B     0B     422  2399 stuck    *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    0    1317
2399- dbfseventsd  0.0  00:00.18 1     0    10    444K   0B     0B     422  422  sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    0    788
2318  node         0.0  00:04.61 10    0    29    73M    0B     0B     2317 2317 sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  59203
2317  node         0.0  00:00.81 11    1    53    33M    0B     0B     2317 913  sleeping *0[1]           0.00000 0.00000    501  203
```

I notice all the Interface Builder processes and searched the system log for Interface Builder: I found this at the same time of the hang:
[image]

Comment: Please use `top -o cpu` and only paste the first few processes. The system load is rather moderate though, so I don‘t see this as the main issue right now.